# EAV vs JSON/XML column approach to store complex user form data in a database?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, json, xml, rdbms

We are working on an internal tool which will essentially be a complex, power-user oriented form app. It is not a dynamic field app - users can't define their own fields.

**Form field types:** The form will contain a mix of the following form field types

- Y/N questions (i.e. radio buttons)
- Single-select dropdowns
- Table mapping interface (i.e. map columns in table A to columns in table B)
- Multi-select dropdowns (some of which are populated by the columns of table B)

**Database:** I briefly considered NoSQL approaches but would prefer this in Azure SQL because the team is very comfortable with relational databases and we will never have issues with data size for this app. Open to revisit this if people feel strongly.

**Options:** from what I've read I have the following options (excluding NoSQL tools)

1. Go full relational using an EAV-style approach
2. Use a JSON/XML data column in SQL to store the form field data

**Considerations**

- Development time
- Relational data integrity (i.e. a user deletes a column from Table B that is used in a multi-select)
- Versioning - the user form is likely to change over time, although slowly and under developer control
- Ease of running migrations, particularly more complex ones that require changes to existing user-entered data as opposed to just schema. An example: combining two yes/no questions into one and needing to update the data accordingly

I have had a hard time finding good resources online to compare pros and cons in these cases. Could anyone here please point me to good articles or information?

Comment: Your question will likely be closed as opinion-based. Also consider performance.

Comment: I hate that these types of questions get lumped as "opinion based", but I would say it's too broad and doesn't lend itself to a satisfactory answer, i.e. just do A, B, C.  That being said: neither of those choices are good options.  EAV is decidedly *not* relational, and JSON (like XML before it) is a mess to deal with.  That said, this SO question/answer may provide some clarity/perspective: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011956/single-fixed-table-with-multiple-columns-vs-flexible-abstract-tables/4013207#4013207